# Facebook PHP SDK request permission

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

This is what I have used till now:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.bla.com/fb_access.php' . $ref);
header('Location:  ' . $loginUrl) ;
```

It works but I don't get the birthday even though it was confirmed so I looked it up and there are tutorials where the code is:

```
$permissions = 'user_birthday';
$login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(['email','scope'=>$permissions]);
return redirect($login_url);
```

But it's not working that way, how to do this right?

There wasn't any problem getting the birthday etc with old SDK.

Comment: what means "not working"? do you get asked for the birthday in the auth process? also, what john doe said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grants the 'user_birthday' permission like this, more example on [github](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/tree/5.x/docs/examples)

And remove the app https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications to grant new permission

```
$permissions = ['email','user_birthday']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

Comment: nvm it works, there was another mistake. Still Zuckerberg is rly annoying with his non necessary never ending BS changes